# How to specify multiple dependencies using --packages for spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming

I have the following as the command line to start a spark streaming job.

```
    spark-submit --class com.biz.test \
            --packages \
                org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.3.0 \
                org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:1.0.0 \
                org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:1.0.0 \
                org.apache.hbase:hbase-server:1.0.0 \
                org.json4s:json4s-jackson:3.2.11 \
            ./test-spark_2.10-1.0.8.jar \
            >spark_log 2>&1 &
```

The job fails to start with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given path is malformed: org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:1.0.0
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.resolveURI(Utils.scala:1665)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.parse$1(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:432)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.parseOpts(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I've tried removing the formatting and returning to a single line, but that doesn't resolve the issue. I've also tried a bunch of variations: different versions, added `_2.10` to the end of the artifactId, etc.

According to the docs (`spark-submit --help`):

> The format for the coordinates should be groupId:artifactId:version.

So what I have should be valid and should reference [this package](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.hbase%7Chbase-common%7C1.0.0%7Cjar).

If it helps, I'm running Cloudera 5.4.4.

What am I doing wrong? How can I reference the hbase packages correctly?

Comment: Is it working fine? In my case I had to add jars via --jars and --driver-class-path also.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A list of packages should be separated using commas without whitespaces (breaking lines should work just fine)  for example

```
--packages  org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.3.0,\
  org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:1.0.0
```

Comment: I found I also had to remove the spaces and line breaks in order to get it to work successfully: `--packages  org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.3.0,org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:1.0.0`...

Answer (score 5):

I found it worthy to use SparkSession in spark version 3.0.0 for mysql and postgres

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('mysql-postgres').config('spark.jars.packages', 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.20,org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.16').getOrCreate()
```

Comment: i never heard of `spark.jars.packages` before and I was a top-end developer (including multiple `spark-sql` and `mllib` contribs)  from 2014 to 2019

Answer (score 1):

@Mohammad thanks for this input.  This worked for me too. I had to load the  Kafka and msql packages in a single sparksession. I did something like this:

`spark = (SparkSession .builder ... .appName('myapp') # Add kafka and msql package .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.26") .getOrCreate())`